# how to include + in start of each <h4> without ::before

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to run the same function on h4::before as it is written on h4

**CSS**

```
.admin-leftnav > ul >li > ul li > h4:before {
    content: "+";
    color: #23366D;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.admin-leftnav>ul>li>h4').click(function(){
     $(".admin-leftnav>ul>li>ul>li>ul").css("background", "transparent");
    panels.slideUp();
    panels2.slideUp();
    $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: _"want to run the same function on h4::before as it is written on h4"_ Not certain what actual Question is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tried **[prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)** ?

`$('.admin-leftnav>ul>li>h4').prepend('<span>+ </span>');`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding + through CSS Add it in Javascript By

```
.prepend('<span>+ </span>');
```